# To get the value from file upload field by jquery

Tags: jquery

i have contact form and there i used a file upload file. now i want to get the value it means the path from the file upload field by jQuery.
 The file upload field has the class named filebrowse and i want to store the value and echo the value in another input field. 
i used this code for retrieve the path

```
var val = jQuery(".filebrowse").val();
console.log(val);
jQuery('.file-input').attr('value', val);
```

it works but it didnot show the value in the input box field. becoz by default the input box is empty so it shown nothing. now i want to display the value in the input box when one browse  file to the file upload field.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. And `.attr('value')` is always bad. There is `.val()` for this purpose. However, you cannot set the value of a file input.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, to get value of file field:

```
$('.filebrowse').change( function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: Ok, file-input is the input box class. but i want to get the value from file upload field , which class is browsefile imentioned before.

Comment: see the answer, it gets value of input field having filebrowser class, did you mean something like that..

Comment: yes i want to get the value after the file upload. only i want the value of file upload field after choose a file to upload

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set the value of a file input, due to security reasons. It would make it possible for malicious javascript to make you set the file, then submit a form programmatically, allowing them to steal any file on your system via forced upload, provided they know the path to it.

Edit - heh, I misread the question and answered based on the example code. It's generally possible to get the filename of the value of a file input, but it will not include the path, again for security reasons.

Comment: what is this means <body onload="getAllFilesAndSendToH4ck3r();">

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and statement there are two parts fetching the value (working) and displaying the value in another input not working.

Selecting the value from the input type=file as per your jquery syntax is the correct way, however sequence is important. To ensure DOM sequence is correct pass the control to the function and then use that in the jquery selector.

OR

Ensure your jquery selector is inside the document ready and bound to the change event.

Option 1: Pass control on change event to the function.

```js
function fileUploadChanged(fileUploader) {
  let path = $(fileUploader).val();
  console.log('Path:=', path);
  $('#fileSelectedOutput').val(path);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- FILE UPLOAD -->
<input type="file" style="width:100%;" class="fu" id="fileUploader" name="fileUploader" onchange="fileUploadChanged(this)" />

<!-- OUTPUT -->
<input id="fileSelectedOutput" type="text" />
```

Option 2: Ensure change event is bound to the control inside document ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fileUploader').change(function() {
    let path = $(this).val();
    console.log('Path:=', path);
    $('#fileSelectedOutput').val(path);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- FILE UPLOAD -->
<input type="file" style="width:100%;" class="fu" id="fileUploader" name="fileUploader" />

<!-- OUTPUT -->
<input id="fileSelectedOutput" type="text" />
```

Answer (score -3):

I understand this post is a bit old but this is what I needed to do in MVC.

```
<input type="file" style="width:100%;" class="fu" id="fileUploader" name="fileUploader" />
```

Then access it by the class.

```
var fileValue = $('.fu').val();
```